# How to parse a document from a string and set the right `documentURL`?

Tags: javascript, dom

I tried to write a very simple crawler in JavaScript (tested in Firefox).

I use the ES6 `fetch` function to get a document in this way:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => (new DOMParser()).parseFromString (text, 'text/html'))
  .then(doc => {
     doc.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(node => {
       fetch(node.href)
         .then(text => (new DOMParser()).parseFromString (text, 'text/html'))
         .then(doc => {
           doc.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(node => {
             console.log (node.href);
           });
         });
     });
  });
```

The problem is the following quoted from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMParser)

> When a DOMParser is instantiated by calling new DOMParser(), it inherits the calling code's principal (except that for chrome callers the principal is set to the null principal) and the documentURI and baseURI of the window the constructor came from.

The first fetch works fine as long as the URL is the same as the URL of the window. But with `querySelectorAll` I collect different anchors from the fetched page in order to fetch also those pages to create DOM trees for each URL. The problem is, that the DOM tree created by `parseFromString` has the wrong `documentURL`. `parseFromString` does not take any URL parameter and instead inherits the `documentURL` from `window`. But this is obviously the wrong URL. And this means all relative links in the fetched document are broken.

How to parse a document from a string and set the right `documentURL`?

```
(new DOMParser()).parseFromString('<html></html>', 'text/html')
```

The attributes `URL` and `documentURL` are both read only.

Comment: Hello again. I presume that the solution I hinted at in your last post didn't work, since you've posted this question? Additionally, the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMParser) seems to indicate that you might be able to pass the correct URI when constructing the parser (in firefox only it seems). Have you tried that already?

Comment: you can't set that manually. you can try injecting in a <base> tag to get some of your links working.

Comment: @CRice Components does not exist anymore in the latest Firefox.

Comment: @dandavis In order to inject a base tag I have to parse the html twice, because I need the dom to inject it. Otherwise I have to parse the header with regexps, which is also no good idea.

Comment: you can `strHtml.replace("</head>","<base href=''></head>")`

Comment: @dandavis Have you ever tried this? `(new DOMParser()).parseFromString('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><base href="http://cr.yp.to"></head><body></body></html>', 'text/html').URL`.  It does not return the URL of the base tag on my system.

Comment: @dandavis This does not do either: `(function (document) { document.innerHTML = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><base href="http://cr.yp.to"></head><body></body></html>'; return document.URL; })(document.implementation.createHTMLDocument())`

Comment: Why is it important that the actual property `URL` holds the correct value? Using `<base url="...">` as @dandavis suggests fixes the base of the relative paths as you request. Do you need to use `URL` for something in addition to fixing the relative paths? You will need to manually change the value for each new page you load (different pages may have different roots), but that's just something you can keep track of in your code as you make requests.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this. Just keep track of the correct origin manually.

```
// Save the origin of the original request.
var origin1 = new URL(url).origin

fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => (new DOMParser()).parseFromString (text, 'text/html'))
  .then(doc => {
     doc.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(node => {
       // Check if node's href is absolute or relative.
       var href = node.getAttribute('href') // use this instead of node.href (node.href is always absolute)
       if (!href.match(/https?:\/\//) {
         // this is a relative url, so
         href = origin1 + href;
       }

       fetch(href)
         .then(text => (new DOMParser()).parseFromString (text, 'text/html'))
         .then(doc => {
           doc.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(node => {
             // See above, check if relative and append to correct
             // origin if so.
             // console.log (node.href);
           });
         });
     });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question correctly the `document` URL would be the `href` of the `<a>` element used to fetch the HTML.

Comment: I take a url, fetch a html page and parse the html into a dom. This dom needs to have the document url of the fetch but not the one of the window.

Comment: @ceving You can use `<template>` element `#document-fragment` instead of `DOMParser()`. `let template = document.createElement("template"); template.innerHTML = /* fetched HTML */; template.content.baseURI // "about:blank"`.

Comment: `template.content.baseURI` does not seem to be writable.

Comment: @ceving What is the issue with the `.baseURI` being `"about:blank"`?  _"And this means all relative links in the fetched document are broken."_ Are you trying to parse the links in the HTML document? What is expected result?